Opening .aprx files in QGIS via SLYR
I'm following this https://mapscaping.com/opening-an-aprx-file-in-qgis/ tutorial on how to open a ArcGIS Pro .aprx-File in QGIS via the SLYR plugin. While it does sound straight-forward, the .aprx-files are not listed in the browser-tab as instructed. I suppose QGIS does not list unknown file extensions, no filters have been set anywhere. Drag-and-Drop will result in the usual error. Am I missing something?

QGIS-Version: 3.30.1-'s-Hertogenbosch
SLYR-Version: 5.0.0 (Community Edition)
OS: macOS 14.5 (23F79)


Since ArcGIS Pro on a mac requires Parallels Desktop version 15 to run. I  expect the issue is your incompatibility. Do you have access to a Windows PC/ Laptop? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/run-pro-on-a-mac.htm

@mapperz ArcGIS Pro is not required. The SLYR plugin can read and convert APRX without ArcGIS.

@Rob looks like APRX conversion is only available with the licensed (proprietary) version, not the community edition - https://north-road.com/slyr/

thanks, that does explain it. I read .aprx in the tags of the community version, so I didn't look for the feature table.

You are likely running the community version of the SLYR plugin.
APRX conversion is currently only available with the licensed (proprietary) version.  From the "Features available at the Community and Licensed Levels" section of the North Road SLYR page:



Tool
Community
Licence




...
...
...


Convert ArcGIS Pro mapx and aprx to QGIS
✗
✓



